# How to fix error in tidy for building table with flextable?

Tags: r, datatables, tidy, flextable

I've created the following list models

```
models_list_1 <- data_long %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(fit = lmerTest::lmer(values ~ group1*group2 + (1 |variable), data = .)) %>% 
  pull(fit) %>% 
  lapply(., function(x) summary(x))
```

If I'm interested to report iteratively each **model coefficients (i.e. `models_lists[[1]]$coefficients`)**contained in each of the model into the list in a table that could be readible into a word/pdf doc created via RMarkdown, which package should I use? How could I set command lines?

I'm keeping on trying with this code, but I have no success at all:

```
models_list_1 %>% 
+   map(~.x %>% map( ~broom::tidy(.x) %>% flextable::flextable()))
```

Since I get this error back

```
Error: No tidy method for objects of class character
```

Here is the dataset

```
    dput(head(dt, 300))
structure(list(A = c("51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54"), group = c("ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", "ss", 
"ss"), group1 = c("first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "third", "third", "third", "third", 
"third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", 
"third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", 
"third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", 
"third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", 
"third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "first", 
"first", "first", "first", "first", "first", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", "second", 
"second", "second", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", 
"third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", 
"third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", 
"third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", "third", 
"third"), group2 = c("first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", "third2", 
"third2", "third2", "third2", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", "first1", 
"first1", "first1", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", "second2", 
"second2", "second2", "second2", "third2"), levels = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "I", "L", "A"), 
    values = c(36.266249143999, 40.2497537510374, 52.6562615613563, 
    38.7854251322917, 41.8513814372223, 53.4315211013568, 42.225202818289, 
    44.9620363291554, 54.6720061653301, 49.6027499123275, 52.9191393648181, 
    58.3814192488233, 59.6145521319282, 38.9293323082768, 41.5757255288692, 
    53.3736061956125, 36.0518342676228, 38.2354241992837, 48.4482007745706, 
    41.5912793982389, 43.6313444719817, 51.7588844293636, 51.0151975537306, 
    51.8548999820214, 54.8884285852803, 57.2129901191072, 41.5280797996481, 
    44.3811350572493, 55.4043480635031, 37.9952376316217, 40.832737550847, 
    51.1350902010486, 42.9676462342307, 45.4532980664456, 52.4927647695136, 
    48.8269996663362, 50.6943936069545, 55.0594399581601, 56.1861244061312, 
    44.9568184734022, 50.7315267276801, 69.5226358864568, 45.7562786082321, 
    50.9187514233206, 66.3120391015512, 49.3498917825026, 54.0549385078639, 
    63.8997702651793, 50.6631153700143, 53.956945721607, 53.8883136457125, 
    56.4672381399526, 43.7462412459985, 51.1145305899379, 68.5017390789352, 
    42.6158553432131, 49.3256274310641, 64.1694182774958, 46.7564973631716, 
    52.6751630316937, 63.2135623121441, 48.2783983450653, 52.3664955738113, 
    55.8320107655818, 57.2596263549935, 42.9525031865941, 47.7489527922653, 
    61.7844254386573, 43.3877828150891, 47.5257406450944, 59.0478140922635, 
    47.1516762040958, 51.0247930281068, 59.5147976810139, 50.0540027107377, 
    52.7129219634566, 53.6511318926034, 57.929523421786, 38.3687848283076, 
    44.8347560099386, 61.8802266972569, 38.2214957027207, 44.0357096847423, 
    58.2398159771844, 44.3270420302871, 49.2255382686988, 59.9938557975616, 
    49.8012637450363, 52.9643729492277, 56.2802731293203, 57.9146894232084, 
    38.8561586714065, 44.4688750982456, 62.1053426662461, 40.850727928741, 
    44.890815628412, 59.5126148464873, 45.6081709919223, 49.3499905372386, 
    61.1212652173052, 46.8389895823356, 47.8708676929109, 55.2453523096677, 
    59.948388157362, 46.0040852905529, 50.6215021234154, 62.955441582096, 
    42.4180949146223, 47.1826777037403, 59.4236740992582, 47.0334703934123, 
    51.1401025064492, 60.6989716871958, 50.8959922798314, 52.9461903511562, 
    57.6816228533581, 60.2186482048953, 58.7161852308419, 60.0972150696175, 
    63.9718285231429, 64.2438131545118, 68.1277616996079, 70.6284861844249, 
    62.5228696634748, 65.0856583318757, 65.4011622649207, 59.2124834739149, 
    60.0673617448764, 58.5582749119015, 55.769014460168, 53.1567164130045, 
    53.2967167211879, 56.3771036171033, 60.3728637305957, 64.0324104861749, 
    67.1194345279475, 60.1688421767607, 62.7218688256241, 63.5845965959489, 
    54.2029104966206, 55.2803284495835, 54.3739004527491, 51.6341165373444, 
    50.1177900590382, 50.5273147797447, 53.5204028349014, 54.7155546750593, 
    57.8890130760117, 59.7498137589838, 54.948916530508, 57.0492948365652, 
    57.6214525086291, 55.2926047469278, 55.7631788386843, 54.2756796701815, 
    52.1404406962007, 56.2230923800622, 57.4801396946797, 63.9681839573434, 
    58.1626338138437, 60.9263261999576, 65.5578942384162, 58.2923447452358, 
    59.7194448456873, 62.4214977980377, 54.4353878740955, 54.5479006397154, 
    56.0470280306929, 54.0909107826167, 50.5450397233114, 52.2429700813803, 
    58.6495542889789, 52.5475427078802, 55.4007038937184, 60.3425870381822, 
    52.8998920931005, 55.1981591776072, 58.9473117496695, 51.2834602731708, 
    52.1656959276459, 55.2945800728906, 55.3259337818231, 49.6163949639344, 
    49.9476494207853, 52.8084738089855, 48.9853666128655, 50.139150314055, 
    53.419327088264, 51.699168728332, 52.2051320695233, 54.1095355776162, 
    51.170034510232, 51.3382471693845, 51.2123481287535, 49.9412935668464, 
    47.8906361654274, 50.0473343786951, 60.1644392609445, 43.5783763523731, 
    45.3895778876135, 54.0527420726564, 48.8666703751771, 49.7969413341886, 
    55.8037374266818, 53.218816657787, 52.5842683296341, 56.3088759867162, 
    56.8649046807896, 51.8106493401599, 52.7824009345564, 63.2788201390174, 
    45.9162542362245, 46.4437448871286, 53.767844291789, 50.6498572804291, 
    51.0105359441602, 55.7463921593046, 55.926045915516, 55.077230852852, 
    55.9614279900414, 55.2628099655258, 50.754416368133, 52.6005799397852, 
    60.5077997492971, 41.5325770962378, 43.1434830625967, 50.3261106575348, 
    45.5631565277737, 47.0375831423404, 51.487626606131, 47.2444464557277, 
    48.4030082283098, 49.3906181732595, 50.9813007346846, 48.7628763185683, 
    51.4302038359579, 63.4030666728381, 43.6909169916252, 47.8276204284005, 
    56.6583986527968, 47.6842545649077, 51.2648003671509, 56.0401855384134, 
    52.1800664086532, 56.6187285539854, 53.6664615799653, 55.0384350436334, 
    47.2314761012372, 49.3492021621468, 54.7401434682908, 43.2733885719763, 
    43.8113276231576, 51.1700388369216, 47.2664045061793, 47.9948715800227, 
    51.9050381096835, 49.7744661856655, 48.7830347342135, 50.2409562222778, 
    50.3616701199615, 55.5414435577812, 57.8124899386777, 61.9003140352528, 
    46.6726350995775, 48.2206106900028, 55.4063001308578, 49.61263548544, 
    49.5768944348476, 56.3721122874941, 50.9864672664597, 49.4927921073265, 
    51.1505332511655, 50.3937914109181, 49.6858443246175, 52.2310074124104, 
    65.0981004360619, 45.9848416398862, 48.5644263351238, 55.0633265321648, 
    50.1591836526911, 51.5140374120639, 53.7899021820967, 53.1104206811284, 
    53.4484460701452, 51.0824297346564, 51.0745588992281, 50.2388856489597, 
    53.9699071086295, 65.4046229884164, 43.398346143465, 46.8512784208735, 
    55.0261915939541, 48.2163881506462, 50.2557183555402, 54.5941383032222, 
    52.2780009055847, 53.0240343383564, 52.9989631400021, 51.6591785051503, 
    55.0374994689839)), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you update your example or example data to something we can run on our machines? The code throws an error.

Comment: Sorry, are you referring to the code I've reported at the very beginning to fit models or something?

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg I've just tried to extend the dataset

Comment: If I run the code you provided with the `dput()` output, we get this error "Error: grouping factors must have > 1 sampled level". I think it's because there is only one level of the ID variable.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Ok, I've extended it furthermore. Just let me know wether it works or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in the gtsummary package that will build and summarize regression models stratified by the `signals` column. The resulting tables can either be merged to have a wide summary of the results, or stacked to have a long summary table. The example below shows the first few rows of stacked results.

I've used `modify_column_unhide()` to show the SE and t-statistic, which are hidden by default. You can similarly hide the ci column if needed with `modify_column_hide()`.

```r
data_long %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = signals, 
    ~ lmerTest::lmer(value ~ COND*SES + (1 |ID), data = .x) %>%
      tbl_regression(),
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack"
  ) %>%
  modify_column_unhide(c(std.error, statistic)) %>%
  as_flex_table()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Comment very instructive. As you could see I'm interested in reporting the following statistics `Estimate Std. Error df t value Pr(>|t|) `. Is there any way to get them reported into the table?

Comment: updated with SE and t-statistic

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll study better ypur genial package ;)

Comment: It is an astonishingly elegant table!!